# Unable to upload file by using curl through SFTP on redhat8

Tags: curl, sftp, redhat

I faced this error "curl: (9) Access denied to remote resource" on redhat 8 after using the command

**curl -k -v --insecure -T {file} sftp://demo1:{password}@{ip}/**

Howerver, it can work on redhat 7 with the same command.
I have no idea why redhat 7 can work but redaht 8 didn't work?

Comment: Aside: `curl -k --insecure` are synonyms; using both doesn't accomplish anything more than one. Because of its generality `curl` errors are often vague; can you connect with the `sftp` _program_ or even `ssh`? If so and either shows the problem, add at least one `-v` and maybe two or three (`ssh` et al `-v` is one of the few cases where repeating an option _does_ make a difference) and look for differences or relevant details. If `sftp` or `ssh` works but `curl` (using `libssh`) doesn't, you'll have to try to find out what libssh does differently or wrong. ...

Comment: ... One major difference in RH8  is that it [applies a systemwide security policy](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/considerations_in_adopting_rhel_8/security_considerations-in-adopting-rhel-8) that might block something required by your server. For example it might use a DSA hostkey, which as mentioned on that page (8.1.7) is now prohibited by default; there may be others not mentioned.